# How do I validate the SSL certificate from an HTTPS connection, using a specific signing certificate?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, x509

I am changing some Ruby code to use the https scheme, but I wasnt happy about setting the SSL verification policy to VERFIY_NONE.
How do I validate the SSL cert from a remote server is genuine ?

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to retrieve a resource from an HTTPS server.

Many people chose to set the HTTP verify_mode to OPENSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE to bypass any
SSL sertificate validation, but getting Ruby to validate an SSL certificate is pretty easy.

Note some people use OpenSSL::X509::Store#set_default_paths to use the default trusted certificates for a system.
If this works for you, cool, but in my case the trusted signing certificate wasnt in the system store. I needed a 
way to validate an internal sites SSL cert using the internally generated, public signing certicate.

One thing you absolutely will need is the public certificate for the entity that signed the sites SSL certificate. In my
case, I had the cert file, but I needed to convert it from DER X.509 certificate (.cer file) to a Base-64 encoded
X.509 certificate, then renaming the CER extension to PEM. Most platforms (Windows, Linux, OSX etc) have certificate management tools for importing and exporting certificates. This was required because Ruby seems to have issues with natively consuming DER certificates.

Once I had the PEM file I wrote the following code

```
url = URI.parse(https_url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
if url.scheme == 'https'
  http.use_ssl = true
  # most people use VERIFY_NONE - change to force cert check
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

  #load the cert file
  cert  = Pathname.new(Dir.pwd) + "cert.pem"
  fail "no certificate file found" unless cert.exist?
  store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
  store.add_cert(OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(cert)))
  http.cert_store = store
end

# get the resource, validating the remote SSL cert first
response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri))
```